# Some folders and files not showing up on PC when connected via USB

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, file-system

My phone doesn't have an SD card in it right now, so all storage is on internal memory. I have a bunch of folders in my Pictures folder that don't show up on my PC when I connect it via USB (but most folders do appear). I know they're there because they appear in my phone's file manager (in both the native Google one and a third-party one). How come I can't see them?

Comment: How do you connect to the computer ? MTP or Mass Storage ?

Comment: @esQmo it's android 6.0 so mass storage is unavailable.

Comment: need to sue Google for my data losing. Did a factory reset and only realise my backup data is not latest.

Comment: You want to sue Google because you did a factory reset and forgot to backup your data. Yeah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a known issue. Go to app manager and find 'external storage' and 'media storage' and clear data and cache for them, then reboot, and wait up to 10 minutes and then connect to PC via USB.
Sometimes media scan apps from play store help if you don't want to reboot.

Comment: What is app manager?

Comment: @Bluefire go to settings>apps

Comment: There's no section for external or media storage.

Comment: Select show system apps when you go to settings>apps

Comment: If your problem is solved please mar answer as correct. A little check mark on the left from question.

Comment: Have the same problem, I do not know how it works, but it is like a magic. Thanks!

Comment: Stopping the DiagMonAgent App works for me. Go to Apps > ... > Show System Apps > DiagMonAgent > Force Stop.

Comment: @jlhoward that does not make any sense since diagnostic monitor agent has little to do with storage, but if it fixes problem for you, great. Also DiagMonAgent is only present on Samsung phones.

Comment: I'd installed a few new apps, and just rebooting the device worked for me, using the latest Android as of 1/12/2019.After reboot explorer took longer to open the storage folder and lots of new folders appeared.

Comment: On a LineageOS 15.1 (Android 8.1) device I did not find this app (or the setting to show system apps). However, a simple reboot of the device and waiting for a minute solved the issue.

Comment: This worked for me on Samsung Galaxy S9.  After clearing the data/cache I did not reboot or wait 10 minutes.  I simply connected the phone to the PC and now all the files are there.  Thank you  Једноруки Крстивоје !

Answer (score 0):

I find another trick that works on Android 8.1, not sure other versions, that you can reboot your phone to recovery mode, specifically I installed TWRP, then the missing folders show up on my computer.

Note, for Android OS developers, if you just flashed the system image, you have to at least boot into desktop once, the computer then can recognize the phone under recovery mode.